# Determine the probability that the sample will contain two shirts B and two shirts C

Tags: probability, statistics, actuarial-science

A factory makes three different types of clothes: clothes A, clothes B, clothes C. The factory produces hundreds of clothes each year, with twice as many clothes B as clothes A. The number of clothes C is twice the amount of clothes A combined clothes B. Four clothes made by the factory are selected at random from all types of clothes produced by the factory in a given year. Determine the probability that the sample will contain two shirts B and two shirts C.

The answer should be 32/243. But I don't know how to get that answer. Kindly help :)

Comment: First find the probability that a random piece of clothing is A (and similarly for B and C). Use the given information about how the prevalences of each type of clothing relate to each other, along with the fact that the three probabilities must sum to 1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, you can consider the probability that you select one clothing from all clothes and it turns out to be A or B or C. We call them $P_A$, $P_B$ and $P_C$. Apparently, $P_A=\frac{1}{9}$, $P_B=\frac{2}{9}$ and $P_C=\frac{2}{3}$. You want to select four pieces containing two B and two C, so there are several possibilities. For example, the first is B, the second is B, the third is C and the fourth is C. Let's denote this by BBCC. The probability for BBCC is $P_B\times P_B\times P_C\times P_C=\frac{16}{729}$. Apart from BBCC, there are more possibilities like BCBC, BCCB, CBBC and so on. Notice that it's like place two B and two C in four cells and once we determine the places for two B, we determine one possibility. So we know the number of possibilities is $C_4^2=6$. The probability for all possibility is the same, that is, $\frac{16}{729}$. So $\frac{16}{729}\times6=\frac{32}{243}$. We get the answer. We consider all orderly possibilities so the result is right for selecting four pieces randomly.

My English is terrible and I'm so sorry about that.